# Right associative operator in F#

Tags: f#

Sometimes I have to write:

```
myList |> List.iter (fun x -> x)
```

I would really like to avoid the parentheses. In Haskell there is an operator for this ($)

It would look like this

```
myList |> List.iter $ fun x -> x
```

I created a custom operator

```
let inline (^!) f a = f a
```

and now I can write it like this

```
myList |> List.iter ^! fun x -> x
```

Is there something like this in F#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to define custom operator with an explicitly specified associativity in F# - the associativity is determined based on the symbols forming the operator (and you can find it in the [MSDN documentation for operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx)).

In this case, F# does not have any built-in operator that would let you avoid the parentheses and the idiomatic way is to write the code as you write it originally, with parentheses:

```
myList |> List.iter (fun x -> x)
```

This is difference in style if you are coming from Haskell, but I do not see any real disadvantage of writing the parentheses - it is just a matter of style that you'll get used to after writing F# for some time. If you want to avoid parentheses (e.g. to write a nice DSL), then you can always named function and write something like:

```
myList |> List.iter id
```

(I understand that your example is really just an example, so `id` would not work for your real use case, but you can always define your own functions if that makes the code more readable).

Answer (score 8):

No, there's nothing like this in a standard F# library. However, you have almost done creating your own operator (by figuring out its name must start with `^`).

[This snippet](http://fssnip.net/4o) by [Stephen Swensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236255/stephen-swensen) demonstrates a **high precedence, right associative backward pipe**, `(^<|)`.

```
let inline (^<|) f a = f a
```

This single-liner from the linked page demonstrates how to use it:

```
{1..10} |> Seq.map ^<| fun x -> x + 3
```

And here is an example how to use it for multi-line functions. I find it most useful for real-world multi-liners as you no longer need to keep closing parenthesis at the end:

```
myList
|> List.map
    ^<| fun x ->
        let ...
        returnValue
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Could you explain why `^` is necessary and what makes `^<<` right associative?

Comment: @KFL, both precedence and associativity is defined by the 1st character of the operator name. Check [MSDN documentation for operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx), scroll to the end of page, "Operator Precedence" section.

Answer (score 0):

In `F#` it's `<|`

So it would look like:

```
myList |> List.iter <| fun x -> x
```

Comment: are you sure? I already tried this but it doesn't really seem to work the way I would expect it to work. For example `[1;2;3;4] |> List.iter <| fun x -> printf "%i" x` doesn't compile either.

Comment: Ironically, `[1;2;3;4] |> (List.iter <| printf "%i ")` would work, but you still need brackets to get precedence off the way.